# How to access a WCF service hosted in Windows service from Java client?

Tags: java, windows, wcf, service

I need to share a reporting module developed in .Net and Crystal reports with Java apps to avoid redeveloping it. Can I use a WCF service hosted in Windows service to share the same with Java apps? I don't want to use IIS server if possible. How can I implement this?

Comment: As far as I remember `WCF` use `SOAP` as transport. You can use `SOAP` from `java`.

Comment: Depending on `WCF` configuration you can communicate via `SOAP` or regular http `REST`

Comment: WCF can develop SOAP-based services that support the WS-* protocol. It is cross-platform and programming language.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf
And support the development of Restful style web services.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model-overview
Besides, Windows NT service can host the wcf like IIS, whether Rest style or SOAP-based services.